# Account info Formatting issues

Tags: php, css, formatting

so I have this little box on my site that displays links about the user when logged in. I just added a feature where it gets how many unread messages the user has and displays it next to messages "Messages (1)". It just messed up the formatting completely and I tried to fix it but it isn't cooperating. I have been fighting it for over an hour, any help would be greatly appreciated.

To see what I am talking about, go to the link and the box is in the top right corner. I am trying to get the links to be inline. So it should read:

My Account   Messages (0)  Logout

right now, the logout is 
in a weird position and I can't seem to resolve it.

URL: http://www.clanrippgaming.net/

Thanks a bunch

Here is the php code:

```
                       echo "<div class='logged_in'>";
                       echo "<div class='welcome'>".$user->data['username'] ;"</div>";                          
                       echo "<div class='account'><a href=\"forums/ucp.php\">My Account</a></div>";
                       echo "<div class='account'><a href=\"forums/ucp.php?i=pm&folder=inbox\">Messages (".$user->data['user_new_privmsg'].')';"</a></div>";
                       echo "<div class='account'><a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a></div>"; 
                       echo "</div>";
```

And the CSS for it:

```
.logged_in {
background-image:url(images/bg_login2.png);
border:3px solid#000000;
outline:1px solid#BDBDBD;
width:304px;
height:55px;
margin-left:-2px;
padding-top:5px;
}

.logged_out {
    margin-right: 22px;
    position: relative;
    }

.logged_out_txt {
    margin-top:-20px;
}

.welcome {
    color:#B40404;
    font-size:22px;
    font-family:"Rockwell";
    padding-left:15px;
    float:left;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.account {
    font-weight:normal;
    list-style:none;
    float:right;
    position:center;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:-5px;
    font-size:16px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    margin-right:15px;
    display: inline;

}

.account a:hover {
    color:#D8D8D8
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<div class="account"><a href="forums/ucp.php?i=pm&folder=inbox">Messages ('.$user->data["user_new_privmsg"].')</a></div>';
```

I think that should do the trick.

My tip: be consistent, choose what you want to use: double quote for attributes? Okay, then stick with that, don't go switching that over mid-code.

Comment: Also: another tip that I saw in your code, echo'ing things like that isn't very efficient. Maybe you should look into using span's or do something like `<? if($loggedIn){ ?> HTML Code to display user panel goes here <? } ?>`. That is a method I like to use, but of course something I like to say: "Why change it if it works the way it should?" :P No problem ;)